# Adjust regex to include 0-100 - regex for monetary values

Tags: regex

My current regex is : `^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$` which allows for numeric values up to 99. I am not the greatest with regex and was wondering could someone help me to adjust this to include numbers in the hundreds, example, 100.

Edit: Its for money values.

For example I want to be able to withdraw money values, for example, 100:99, not 100:100.
It cannot be negative, and my program already prevents values less than 1 being entered.

Thanks

Comment: Why use regex for numerics? Why don't use normal comparison? It seems you also are trying to parse float values. But then what about scientific notation?

Comment: And what is the limit 100 or 999 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex for `0..100` range (both inclusive):

```
^([0-9]{1,2}|100)$
```

OR for your example:

```
^([0-9]{1,2}|100)([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: OP wants to allow float values, it seems

Comment: Yes realized and edited accordingly. Would have likes some examples from OP to be more clear though.

Comment: Apologies, its being used for money values.

Comment: Ok did it work for you? If not provide some example inputs as well.

Comment: I think you don't want to allow `0.100`, do you?

Comment: You regex succeeds for 100.100 which is not valid value I suppose.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes you are right i do not want 0.100, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski Yes you are correct, that is not what I want.

Comment: @Gman: Requesting 3rd time, please provide some valid example input values.

Comment: @anubhava It works for 100, but `100.100` works also. My programmed actually handles this well though, if my balance was 200:70, when i withdraw 100:100, it results in the balance 100;60

Comment: You original regex allows `00.00` and is that a valid value?

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski that was ment of anubhava

Comment: @anubhava please see above in question

Comment: @anubhava my program does not allow for values less than 1 so this is not needed for me. But it is a good observation

Comment: I have already seen that and it doesn't mention whether `00.00` is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

This should do: `^[0-9]{1,3}([,.][0-9]{1,3})?$`

Comment: Allows values >100, which is obviously not what the OP expects. And there were no reason to change the decimal mask.

Comment: OP said "in the hundreds, example, 100.", so values > 100 should be fine.  I agree the specification is vague, at best.

Comment: @Richard: AFAIK "hundreds" means 3 digits - my suggestion does the job. Second part also does not seem to be decimal because it has a comma also. Please see carefully before you down vote.

Comment: @RaviH: Title was misleading and message was unclear, especially before the question was edited. It's suggesting that "100" is the upper limit. And in many (many !) countries comma is decimal separator (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma ). So i'm still thinking your answer wasn't good, anubhava's is better. But i'm agree about the fact that the question is unclear, sorry for downvote...

Answer (score 0):

```
((^(100)([.][0]+)?$)|(^[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]+)?$))
```

This regular expression is for 0.0000.... to 100.000000....